# When do we need to explicitly instantiate a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

Let's say we have a template function:

```
template <class T> T max(T a, T b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Since the compiler doesn't perform any implicit type conversion during template argument deduction, we can invoke `max(2, 5.5)` in these two ways:

1. Using casting : `max(static_cast<float>(2), 5.5f);`
2. Using explicit template instantiation : `max<float>(2, 5.5);`

Second case makes sense to me, but when do we do the explicit template instantiation in the given below way (instantiating without invoking the function `max` with *char* type):

```
template char max(char a, char b);
```

What do we achieve out of it?

Comment: explicit instantiation allows to provide declaration without definition in other TU.

Comment: ^ -- Which is useful if your template can be applied only to a limited set of types, all known in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a library then the templates not invoked by the library's code will not be implemented, therefore the library may be missing some functions that you intended to provide.
The explicit instantiation will force the compiler to create an implementation for the specified template, even if no calls to it have been made.

When you finally link your library with the client application then the linker will find the implementation for the types that your library supports.

Maybe an explanation from a native English speaker will be clearer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicit-instantiation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, the native English speaker link for the article you pointed is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicit-instantiation